# Is this enough to secure my members only area?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication

I have created a login form which redirects me to another(members area page) after a successful login.

Now as you know the link of the members area is visible, so, if anyone type this link in the browser it becomes easily accesible. What I did to preven it is to assign the username after a successful login to the session and after that I placed the below `php` small code inside of my main `HTML`

```
<body>
    <?php 
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
        echo 'welcome: '. $_SESSION['username'];
        }
        else{
           header( 'Location: index.html');
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Basically it checks, if there is a `username` in the session and if yes I'm letting the user in, else I'm redirecting him to the index page.

Is my code secure enough? Can a hacker assign a session value and login without any authorization? I know that it is simple, but I'm a newbie in php, so I would like to know, if I'm on the right path.

Comment: You may want to stop execution after the header() call to not render the whole page anyway.

Comment: If that was true, everyone would be a security expert

Comment: Using SSL will help improve security as well.

Answer (score 6):

> Can a hacker assign a session value

Not in a direct way.  Session data is kept server-side, so only your code and other code running on the server has access to set session variables.  The cookies that set up sessions do not contain the keys/values, they only contain an ID for which the server loads the session data from disk.  Of course if you have a security vulnerability in any of your code or other code on your server, then yes a hacker can do whatever they want.

> What I did to preven it is to assign the username after a successful login to the session and after that I placed the below php small code inside of my main HTML

A client doesn't have to follow a redirect. It isn't clear what your real script looks like.  Just remember that if you don't want the client seeing something, don't send it from your server.

Also, you should not be setting headers after there is any output.  Headers are always sent before content.  If this works for you, it's because you are getting lucky with a buffer.  Don't mix your authentication logic with your HTML presentation.

Comment: It's more words saying the same thing.

Comment: @Majenko I disagree with you there.  I'm explaining how sessions work.  But, I also up-voted your answer since it was at least mildly helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the naswer! So, if I place my php code before the  `HTML` content there should be no problems? :)

Comment: @chility See my comment on your question (and told another way in this answer), if you just call `header()` and still draw the rest of the page, the client will see everything anyway, and _then_ possibly redirect. You'll not want to generate the page after you've decided that the user should be redirected.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ok, but how do I stop the HTML for being drawn?

Comment: @chility For example by doing `else { header( 'Location: index.html'); return; }`

Comment: @chility Separate your template from your logic a bit.  Do all of your PHP logic before you even output any HTML.   You can end your script early with `exit()` or `die()`, but if you're structuring things correctly it will be a matter of simply not calling your template code.

Answer (score 0):

Only your scripts running on the server have access to the session store.  So, it's all a question of how secure and robust your scripts are...

Comment: I agree that this *is* an answer; it directly addresses the question asked. It's short, and possibly could include more information like Brad's answer above did, but it still **is** an answer. (and happens to be correct, to boot).